# Imbalance between errors in data summary and tree visualization in Weka

Tags: weka, j48

I tried to run a simple classification on the *iris.arff* dataset in Weka, using the J48 algorithm. I used cross-validation with 10 folds and - if I'm not wrong - all the default settings for J48.
The result is a 96% accuracy with 6 incorrectly classified instances.

Here's my question: according to [this](https://weka.wikispaces.com/What+do+those+numbers+mean+in+a+J48+tree%3F) the second number in the tree visualization is the number of the wrongly classified instances in each leaf, but then why their sum isn't 6 but 3?

---

[image: Data summary]

---

[image: My decision tree]

EDIT: running the algorithm with different test options I obtain different results in terms of accuracy (and therefore number of errors), but when I visualize the tree I get always the same tree with the same 3 errors. I still can't explain why.

Answer (score 0):

The second number in the tree visualization is not the **number** of the wrongly classified instances in each leaf - it's the total **weight** of those wrongly classified instances.
Did you, by any chance, weigh some of those instances with 0.5 instead of 1?

Another option is that you are actually executing two different models. One where you use the full training set to build the classifier (classifier.buildClassifier(instances)) and another one where you run Cross-validation (eval.crossValidateModel(...)) with 10 train/test folds. The first model will produce the visualised tree with less errors (larger trainingset) while the second model from CV produces the output statistics with more errors. This would explain why you get different stats when changing the test set but still the same tree that is built on the full set.

For the record: if you train (and visualise) the tree with the full dataset, you will appear to have less errors, but your model will actually be overfitted and the obtained performance measures will probably not be realistic. As such, your results from CV are much more useful and you should visualise the tree from that model.